# Taking user input in Rust and dynamically correlate it to loaded modules

Tags: rust

I am relatively new to Rust. I am trying to make an interactive CLI tool, the user can specify modules and commands to run in that module (i.e. "network get-routing-table" would try to run a function in the "network" module that gets the routing table).

I want to write this in such a way that doesn't require a hand-written map that has to be constantly updated every time I add/remove a module. Ideally I would just want a loop that iterates over the loaded modules and does a direct comparison of the user input and module name (i.e. `if user.input[0] in loaded_modules { ... }`) Is this possible?

And what is the best way for me to go about correlating a users input to the name of a loaded module? Using the above example again, how can I take the string "network" and call something like `network::handle_input(rest_of_the_user_input)`?

I initially tried using a enum to register all the loaded modules (still not ideal for me), but beyond the problem of maintenance there is also the issue that it doesn't seem very easy to iterate enums and I would also still need to translate them to strings, I definitely got the impression that this was not the right tool for the job.

The most obvious solution seems to be a match block to register the modules, but I am hoping there is a cleaner way doesn't require explicit registering.

Comment: What's a 'loaded module' supposed to mean? Rust binaries are usually statically linked without any loading and all module information is only there at compile time.

Comment: Apologies, I think I've used the wrong terminology, I guess the right wording would be "modules that exist in the binary". So if a user tried to run "thisdoesntexist do-a-thing" it would throw an error. So I simply want the program to look up if a module exists without having to explicitly type the name of each module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to make something like this work, of varying levels of boilerplate.

The way `cargo` handles subcommands is by making individual executables for every subcommand. So when you run `cargo fmt`, it actually runs the `cargo-fmt` executable. [You can make as many executables in your package as you want.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries) All source files in `src/bin/` are included by default and can be compiled at the same time with `cargo build --bins`.

This is good for when you want to add or remove subcommands without recompiling the other binaries, but if you have a lot of shared logic, this will take up much more disk space than a single binary. It also incurs the overhead of launching two executables instead of one.

As far as having it in a single binary, you can decrease repetition with a macro. A declarative macro can expand a list of module names into a map or match statement connecting strings to module items.

Here's a macro that takes a list of module names, declares them, and creates a function that calls a function called `entry` from each module.*

```rs
macro_rules! import {
    ($($module:ident),* $(,)?) => {
        $(
            mod $module;
        )*

        fn call_module(input: &str) -> bool {
            match input {
                $(stringify!($module) => $module::entry(),)*
                _ => return false
            }
            true
        }
    };
}

import! {
    a,
    b,
    c,
}

fn main() {
    let arg = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("subcommand not given");
    if !call_module(&arg) {
        panic!("module {arg} not found");
    };
}
```

This requires that in `a.rs`, `b.rs`, and `c.rs`, a `pub fn entry()` exists, but of course, you can change this to do whatever you want, like returning a trait object or spawning a task.

If you want to retrieve the module names without listing them out manually, however, you will need a procedural macro.

It's also possible to dynamically link them as separate libraries, but this is more complicated.

Another way is to leverage a more dynamic language, either by calling your rust from it through FFI, or by embedding its interpreter inside your binary. There's lots of crates for creating bindings to other languages, such as [PyO3](https://docs.rs/pyo3/) for Python and [mlua](https://docs.rs/mlua/) for Lua.

---

* Match statements on strings are [only efficient for a few hundred items](https://github.com/lmammino/mega-match-vs-phf) at the moment, after which [`phf`](https://docs.rs/phf/) becomes faster. That's probably enough for subcommands, but good to know.

Comment: Wow this is some great information, thanks! Would do be able to demonstrate what a macro might look like that can achieve this? I have very little experience writing macros and this idea is a bit confusing. I am beginning to understand that this question doesn't really have a simple answer and might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @mCloud I added the macro

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for all your help on this, very insightful!